# Recover specific files from a damaged hard drive

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, ext4, hard-drive-recovery, ddrescue

I'm trying to recover some 3-5GB of NEF files which were not yet backed up at the time of the crash.

This is a 418GB ext4 partition and when mounted with `-o ro,noload` I can list the directory where the files are but I get an error if I try to copy them. I'm currently running `ddrescue -n --direct --no-trim --sector-size=4096` and while it started reasonably fast, it has since slowed down considerably. After a restart six hours ago, currently the average speed is about 38KB/s. So far it has rescued 7.5GB.

Given the low speed of `ddrescue` - is there any way to copy only the files that I need? I'm not interested much in the rest of the disk.

Comment: There might be but honestly it already sounds like the HDD is already on its last leg, I personally, would allow it to finish what it can no matter how long it will take. Even if you restarted now there is a real possibility recovery wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, but feel free to post another answer if you have a better idea.

Here is what I did. First, I mounted the partition as read-only:

```
mount -o ro,noload /dev/sdb6 /badhdd
```

Then I used `find` to run ddrescue on each file:

```
mkdir ~/rescue
mkdir ~/rescue-log
find /badhdd/path/to/directory -type f -name "*.NEF" -exec ddrescue -vvvv -P1 -n --no-trim /badhdd/path/to/directory/{} ~/rescue/{} ~/rescue-log/{} \;
```

For any files with errors I did:

```
ddrescue -vvvv -P1 --reverse /badhdd/path/to/directory/{} ~/rescue/{} ~/rescue-log/{}
```

After 72 hours I have recovered 65 files out of just over 400 with an average size of 10MB. The speed varies a lot - it takes less than 10s to recover some files, while others take 5-6 hours.

This means that if I manage to recover only the files that I actually need, the recovery will take about 18-20 days, as opposed to over 120 for the entire partition.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'd also suggest duplicating the copies on a regular basis; something like running `watch -n60 cp -vR ~/rescue ~/rescuecopy` from within a separate terminal might be a good start. Onto separate physical media would be even better. That way you have an extra copy of what you managed to recover, in case the drive you are recovering *onto* fails at an inopportunate moment.

Comment: `mount -o ro,noload /dev/sdb6 /badhdd` does not work, it says `/badhdd: invalid file system`

Comment: @bzero try specifying the file system type:  `mount -t TYPE [...]` Replace `TYPE` with the actual fs type.

Comment: @bzero replace /badhdd with your actual external HDD. /badhdd was used for demonstration purposes by the author!